# Why isn't it always required to use the `done()` callback with mocha?

Tags: mocha.js

In the Mocha.js docs there are 3 kinds of example of `beforeEach` usage.

1. `beforeEach(function (done) {...` where a done callback must be run so that Mocha knows the hook has completed
2. `beforeEach(function () { return promise...` where a promise is returned so no callback is needed.
3. `beforeEach(function () {...` where no callback is referenced *and* no promise is returned.

Any of these on their own would seem fine, but how does mocha distinguish between case (1) and cases (2) and (3)? How can Mocha detect whether a callback was defined as a parameter passed to `beforeEach` (case 1) and is therefore required to be called before proceeding with tests as opposed to cases 2 and 3 where no callback is passed in and therefore tests can begin as soon as the `beforeEach` function completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple and can be discovered by reading the source code of Mocha, which is what I just did. What Mocha does is check whether the function you pass to `beforeEach` or any other hook, or `it` takes arguments by checking the `length` field of the function. The following interactive session with Node.js illustrates the point:

```
> function foo() {}
undefined
> foo.length
0
```

`foo.length` is 0 because `foo` does not take any arguments.

```
> function bar(done) {}
undefined
> bar.length
1
```

`bar.length` is 1 because `bar` takes one argument.

In Mocha, this test is done in the constructor for `Runnable` objects:

```
this.async = fn && fn.length;
```

Every hook is modeled as a `Hook` object, which is a derived class of `Runnable`. And each test is modeled as a `Test` object, which is a derived class of `Runnable` too.